# How to convert string to bytes32 properly?

Tags: solidity, web3js, bytes32

In my solidity I'm using a mapping like this:

```
mapping(bytes32 => uint) items;

constructor() {
   items["test"] = 2;
}   

function getItem(bytes32 key) returns(uint) {
   return items[key];
}
```

My question is now how to call the function in JS using web3 1.0? I have to convert the string to hex. Using `web3.utils.stringToHex("test")` gives me 0x74657374. Using that I'm getting `invalid bytes32 value`. The function `web3.utils.asciiToHex` returns `0x7465737400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` which looks for me like a different value. The function call succeeds but I don't get the expected result value of 2. 
I also tried `web3Utils.padLeft(web3Utils.stringToHex(params[index]), 64);` which gives `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000074657374`. Function call succeeded but result value is also 0 not 2.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on web3 v0.x, then:

- Use [`web3.fromAscii`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromascii) before you send the string to the smart contract
- Use [`web3.toAscii`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii) after you read the string from the smart contract

If you're on web3 v1.x, then:

- Use [`web3.utils.asciiToHex`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#asciitohex) before you send the string to the smart contract
- Use [`web3.utils.hexToAscii`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoascii) after you read the string from the smart contract